# Wordpress / Woocommerce :: Form-Based Payment Gateway Option

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

Can someone advice me how to integrate our company's own payment gateway to woocommerce? I have the documentation of it, and I understand it very well. My problem is how to implement it to woocommerce as a form-based payment gateway (http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/)

All I want is to change the link of "Place Order" button to our own payment gateway. should I have to change something at CHECKOUT page?

Please advise. I'm very new to woocommerce.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey i too had a same problem. just go to path of plugin woocommerce and open woocommerce.php it will be in

> C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce

and in that you include your own payment calss

```
function core_gateways( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_BACS';
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Cheque';
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_COD';
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Mijireh';
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Paypal';
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Firstdata';
    return $methods;
}
```

if your gate way is authorize, you add in ti as

```
$methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Authorize';
```

You will get an option in the check out page then you can create your own code to process when that gateway is selected.